# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate doesn't dismiss my modal

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am presenting a modal view in fullscreen with bounce disabled (false).
I am attempting to close it using UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, but I am encountering difficulties as the dismissal isn't functioning.

While I managed to get it to dismiss using UICollectionViewDelegate through the scrollViewDidScroll method, my objective is to achieve the dismissal utilizing UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate. However, I'm facing challenges in making this approach work as intended. Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
        transitioningDelegate = self
    }
....
```

```
extension MyViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1.0
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard
            let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as? MyViewController,
            let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)
        else {
            transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
            return
        }

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            fromView.alpha = 0.0
        }) { _ in
            fromViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Make the dismiss work using UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate